# Creating Scrum Product backlog for an eCommerce multivendor, multi department Portal

Tags: agile, e-commerce, scrum

I am a .NET developer wanting to build an SaaS based ecommerce system with B2B and CMS  features (custom built, ASP.NET MVC preferably or using Dotnetnuke that enables SaaS scenarios). Technologies would be mainly Microsoft's (.NET 3.5, 4.0, Ajax, jQuery, Asp.NET MVC or MVP, SQL Server/MySql, EF 2.0, NHibernate, WCF, WPF, Window mobile 6.5, TDD/DDD).

I have a developer/architect asking me to produce a product backlog with ecommerce business requirements. I need to educate myself in how to do it intelligently and rapidly and I would use methodology outlined in this course:
[Agile Requirements Modeling - Personas, User Stories and Use Cases](http://www.softo2.com/education/catalog/R20.htm) (I cannot attend it and I need to educate myself on how to best follow these practices).

Can somebody recommend any resources (books, videos, open source code, user manuals, real-world samples of product log) that will help me understand modern ecommerce business, interaction design patterns (since I want to have some GUI functionality built it and that will become some of product log items) and using Agile Scrum methodology?
The best resource that would help me would be some real world ecommerce Product Backlog and Sprint iterations with possibly prototypes and interaction diagrams.

I know I ask a lot, but I am detailing my wish.

Thanks,
Rad

Answer (score 2):

I've suggested it before and I'll suggest it again - [The Art of Agile Development](http://jamesshore.com/Agile-Book/) is a great book.

Mike Cohn's [User Stories Applied](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/books/2) is also a good read.

[About Face](http://www.cooper.com/insights/books/#aboutface3) is always suggested for interaction design but I've found it a bit dull to read.

As for something that will help you 'understand modern ecommerce business' ... why aren't you talking to someone who understands the field?

The other thing that strikes me is how you've managed to come up with a list of technology choices without, it seems, having an understanding of the domain or the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Agile Estimating and Planning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131479415) for an overview of how to organise the project. For a dot net focussed book I'd recommend [Applying Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202). There are many other excellent books that could be useful, but I'd begin with those.

Additionally keep an eye on [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/) for a constant barrage of excellent material and talks. For example, here's a recent one on [project metrics](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/agile-project-metrics).

Answer (score 0):

I too would highly recommend the Art of Agile Development book by Shore and Warden.

From what you've written i'm guessing you're new to Scrum so i'd also get Agile Project Management with Scrum by Ken Schwaber. Its a quick read and introduces the players in a Scrum project. It teaches through case studies and anecdotes. Want to know who is meant to create the product backlog and its purpose. Its in here.

There's quite a bit of discussion about the usefulness of product logs. I like the ideas about an idealog in [this users post](http://stateofflux.com/2009/04/10/is-the-product-backlog-an-idealog/). A product log to me follows approach A.